# TestFlight: No SKSpriteNodes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, testflight

I try to test my SpriteKit Game in TestFlight. But when I install the Build via TestFlight the App just shows a gray screen with my AdMob Banner which I have integrated in the Storyboard. But it seems that the whole GameScene is not loaded. 
Installing directly with the cable works fine.

Could it be related to the fact that I have deleted the GameScene.sks file?

I also get this error message some times:

[image]

I am using Xcode 6.3 and Swift 1.2

Comment: I don't think that this is an effect of TestFlight; are you sure you didn't just forget to set up everything properly? Try installing a clean build on your tethered device. TF might also not yet support Swift 1.2 (but it should be backwards-compatible).

Comment: I don't know what I could change to set up everything property. It already worked with TF.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved the problem.
The problem was, that I deleted the GameScene.sks file. I restored the file an now it works.